# How to avoid optimized for iphone 6 high resolution ios app start in ipad native mode?

Tags: ios

I have an app which been added **UILaunchStoryboardName** to make it to launch in iphone 6 high resolution mode.

However, when I install the app on ipad (app is set to work on iphone only, **UIDeviceFamily** only contains value **"1"**) with ios 8, it starts in native mode instead of 1x, 2x compatible mode.

I have tested on ipads with ios 5.1, 6.x and 7.x, all old versions before ios 8.0 respect the Info.plist and launch the iphone app in compatible mode. However, ipad with ios 8 seems will use **UILaunchStoryboardName** blindly and launch app in native mode.

The dilemma is, if I remove **UILaunchStoryboardName** key from Info.plist, the app won't launch in high resolution mode of iphone 6 and 6+. But if I add it, app will not only works on iphone 6 with high resolution mode, but also launch in ipad with ios 8.0 in native mode which is not I want since I have another version for ipad only.

Could someone find a way to do that or it's the way of Apple to force all apps to be universal?

Is there a way to make the app use the iphone 6 and 6+ high resolution mode, and not launch in native mode on ipad with ios 8.0?

Comment: Maybe say which key you are referring to...

Comment: The site editor remove all the key words inside "<" and ">" tags. I have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution: set your launch storyboard for iPhone only.  **In the info.plist replace UILaunchStoryboardName with UILaunchStoryboardName~iphone.** Now the app will run native on iPhone and NOT run native resolution on iPad, meaning you can hold off on optimizing for iPad Pro.